# Always return same instance of class

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
WSConnection: function() {
   var instance = new Connection();
   return instance;
},
```

How to I tweak this code (avoid making multiple instances) so that I always get same instance of my `Connection` class when I call `WSConnection();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be:

```
WSConnection: function() {
   this.instance = this.instance || new Connection();
   return this.instance;
},
```

Seems to me it is the most compact of all possible solutions..

Comment: Explanation: `this.*` will create variables that persist between calls. `var instance` will create a private variable related to the current instance.

Comment: I would say calling `this.*` a *static* variable is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Create a local variable next to the object that `WSConnection` is defined on:

```
var connectionInstance;

// ... {
WSConnection: function() {
   return connectionInstance || connectionInstance = new Connection();
},
// ... }
```

If the object is itself a class then use a "private class" variable instead (`this.connectionInstance`).

Answer (score 1):

If this use case is specific to the `WSConnection` function, use a lazily (or non-lazily—suit yourself) initialized global:

```
var _instance = null;  // you can also just create the singleton instance here (eager/non-lazy initialization)

WSConnection: function() {
   if (!_instance)
       _instance = new Connection();
   return _instance;
}
```

However, if this is an intrinsic quality of the `Connection` class altogether, turn it into a singleton; there are several ways to do that (e.g. how Java would do it), but since Javascript is a flexible language, I'd do it this way:

```
Connection = new Connection()  // do this at a global scope
```

Now you will just use `Connection` to get the single global instance and not `new Connection`; this also means that you probably won't need the `WSConnection` function any more. Also, this ensures nothing will be able to create another instance of `Connection` (if that's what you need, that is)

Answer (score 1):

Create the instance beforehand. You can wrap your containing object in a function, so that the instance variable is not global:

```
var someobj = (function() {

  var instance = new Connection();

  return {

    WSConnection: function() {
      return instance;
    }

  };

})();
```

Alternatively use lazy creation, i.e. create it on the first use:

```
var someobj = (function() {

  var instance = null;

  return {

    WSConnection: function() {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Connection();
      }
      return instance;
    }

  };

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WSConnection: (function(){
    var instance = null;
    return function() {
       if( !instance ){
           instance = new Connection();
       }
       return instance;
    };
})()
```

Comment: Might be a bit hard to follow for a beginner? :)